# How to insert a video into HTML?

Tags: html

```
<html><body><video src="C:\Users\vps\Desktop\v.mp4" width="50%" controls>
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the 'video' element. Try using the 'object' element listed further down the page.</p></video><p>If you can see the video controls but the video doesn't play when you click the "Play" button, your browser might not support this file type (i.e. <code>Ogg</code>). In this case, try the same code, but with a different file format.</p>enter code here</video></body></html>
```

Comment: Your HTML codes are awful. Try to learn from basics. Also, the `<video>` source you want should be a relative path, instead of an absolute local path; it just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```html
<video width="300" height="400" id="vid" controls>
  <source src="https://developer.apple.com//live-photos/assets/boy.mov" type="video/mp4">
  
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer the below link, This will explain about adding video file.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video

Comment: This is not an answer, and please don't only give links. It works best to provide sample codes. And no w3schools please.